# OPenLayers 3.18.2 Is there any way to see when several placemarks superimposed on the same positions?

Tags: openlayers-3

I use the latest version of Openlayers 3, and before I asked this question on **[Is there any way to see when several placemarks superimposed on the same positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866107/is-there-any-way-to-see-when-several-placemarks-superimposed-on-the-same-position)** but not yet functional.
As the figure below, Google Earth, we have a way to see it. Thank you. 
[image: image2]
[image: image1]

Comment: There is ol.source.Cluster: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to see when several placemarks superimposed on the same positions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866107/is-there-any-way-to-see-when-several-placemarks-superimposed-on-the-same-positio)